# Flask wtforms DataRequired validator tiggers (instead of custom or default validator) when wrong data type submitted as input

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms, customvalidator

Trying to attach a `DataRequired()` and custom validator, `validate_someNumber` to a `FloatField`. But I am having a hard time understanding the feedback from the form field errors when the validation errors are raised. Here are my requirements for the field in question:

- There should be data
- The field should only allow a single numeric value
- The field should only allow a maximum whole number placement to the hundred's. ex: maximum 999
- The field should only allow a single decimal place. ex: 999.9

form.py

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import FloatField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from validators import validate_someNumber

class MyForm(FLaskForm):
    someNumber = FloatField('Some Number', validators=[DataRequired(), validate_someNumber])
```

validator

```py
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError

def validate_someNumber(form, field):
    if field.data is not None:
        whole_number = int(field.data)
        decimal_places = len(str(field.data).split('.')[1]) if '.' in str(field.data) else 0
        if whole_number > 999 or decimal_places > 1:
            raise ValidationError('Some Number must be less than or equal to 999 and have only one decimal place')
```

flask template

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('someTemplate') }}">
    <div>
        <label for="{{ form.someNumber.id }}">{{ form.weight.label }}</label>
        {{ form.someNumber }}
    </div>
    {% for error in form.someNumber.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ error }} debugging info: {{ form.someNumber.data }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

And finally my route

```py
@app.route("/someTemplate", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def someTemplate():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f"You have submitted an entry", "success")
        print(form.data)
        return render_template("someTemplate.html", form=form)
    return render_template("someTemplate.html", form=form)
```

Then I try to submit input like "totallyNotNumeric" and the UI renders the `DataRequired` warning message, "This field is required". **Why would it not raise the "This is not a valid float" message instead?**

That seems to be the message closest to the field Class. I tested a plain `FloatField` without validators and it passed the '... not a valid float' message to the errors list when I tried using alpha-numeric input???

Furthermore, I noticed my custom validator works. When entering something like, "111.111". I get my custom error message. So I thought let me try validating the data type in my custom validator as well. So I modified it like this:

```py
if field.data is not None:
    whole_number = None
    decimal_places = None
    if isinstance(field.data, (int, float)):
        whole_number = int(field.data)
        decimal_places = len(str(field.data).split('.')[1]) if '.' in str(field.data) else 0
     else:
        raise ValidationError('someNumber must be a number')

    if whole_number > 999 or decimal_places > 1:
        raise ValidationError('someNumber must be less than or equal to 999 and have only one decimal place')
```

This did not work. Any advice? Am I missing something super simple or misunderstanding a core concept of flask forms? wtforms? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific reason to use the DataRequired validator here. When used, previous errors (e.g. processing errors) are removed from the field if the data is empty.
Change from [`DataRequired`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/validators/#wtforms.validators.DataRequired) to [`InputRequired`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/validators/#wtforms.validators.InputRequired) and it should give you the familiar error message "This is not a valid float".